# Running two instances of Azure VM

Tags: sharepoint-2010, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure VM role. I created a separate VHD (uploaded to page blob) for storing SQL data files (to overcome data persistence issue with VM role). The SharePoint 2010 has been configured on VM. I want to run 2 instances of Azure VM, where I am faining as mounting the data VHD in write mode on 2 instances is not possible. Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Joannes said:

1. A Cloud Drive may be mounted by exactly one writer, but you can make any number of read-only snapshots. This won't help with a scale-out scenario that you're describing, but I just wanted to clarify.
2. SharePoint 2010 is not a supported configuration in a VM Role currently. There's licensing, compatibility with SQL Azure to consider, scale-out, and potentially other issues. Same goes with installing SQL Server in a VM Role.
3. Support issues aside, you could look into Azure Connect as a way to reach an on-premise SQL Server instance. This alleviates your need to store SQL Server data files in a Cloud Drive. This will have bandwidth-related performance and cost implications, but it's certainly an option.

Answer (score 1):

CloudDrive is not intended for scaling out. In other words, a blob can be mounted by no more than 1 VM at the same time. This limitation is very unlikely to be lifted in the future, as a single blob is note intended to support scalable writes.